# Symfony2, How to set attribute class depending on value?

Tags: php, symfony

I know the solution with twig, but this is not cool. Maybe someone knows a solution with form type.

I want set class(CSS) for select depending on default value, for example:

> ```
> <select>
>     <option value="r" selected="selected">read</option>
>     <option value="rw">read-write</option>
>     <option value="n">no-access</option>
> </select>
> ```

I want set class to **select** like:

> ```
> <select class="select-r">
>     <option value="r" selected="selected">read</option>
>     <option value="rw">read-write</option>
>     <option value="n">no-access</option>
> </select>
> ```

Form type:

```
class UserDefaultAccessSettingType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $choice = array(User::ACCESS_READ => 'read', User::ACCESS_WRITE => 'read-write', User::ACCESS_DENIED => 'no-access');

        $builder
            ->add('month_report', 'choice', array(
                'choices'   => $choice,
                'required'  => true
            ))
            ->add('quarterly_report', 'choice', array(
                'choices'   => $choice,
                'required'  => true
            ))
            ->add('semi_annual_report', 'choice', array(
                'choices'   => $choice,
                'required'  => true
            ))
            ->add('annual_report', 'choice', array(
                'choices'   => $choice,
                'required'  => true
            ))
        ;
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => '\backend\backendBundle\Entity\UserDefaultAccessSetting',
        ));
    }


    public function getName()
    {
        return 'UserDefaultAccessId';
    }
}
```

Comment: This should be in twig, not in PHP. PHP should know nothing about the styles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the field [**attr**](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#attr) option. According to your code, you assign the choices with your `$choice` array, so the default choice will be the the first value in the array.
You could do something like this:

```
->add('month_report', 'choice', array(
    'choices'  => $choice,
    'required' => true
    'attr'     => array('class' => 'select-' . array_keys($shoice)[0])
))
```

If you also want to change the class dynamically depending on the choice the user selects, you need to write some JS for that.

That said, I don't know why you say it *"is not cool"* to do this in Twig, because as it is style, it probably should be in the view component of your app... In fact, if you're writing JS to handle this anyway, why would you duplicate the presentation logic in the form builder?

Comment: This is not what I meant. I want set class for select **depending** on value:   'r' => 'select-r', 'rw' => 'select-rw', 'n' => 'select-n'

Comment: And how are you setting the default value? I can't see nothing in your code, you just create a hard-coded `$choice` array, and the default value will be `'read'` because it's the 1st one... You said depending on **default** value, or did you mean **selected** value?

Comment: Suddenly using function setDefaultOptions(). Yes, I mean selected value.

Comment: @MaxLipsky so I understand that you want to change the CSS class depending on the choice that is selected at the moment, and if the user changes the option, the CSS class changes?

Comment: Exactly. And if the user changes the option, I can change class using JS. Of course I can set classes using Twig or JS... but maybe has another way.

Comment: @MaxLipsky I edited the answer - that's the best I can do with the details you provided. If that's not what you were looking for, please edit your question, because you didn't express your particular issue correctly...